# The program 'keytool' can be found in the following packages

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, keytool

I need SHA1 certificate fingerprint to get Google Map API key but when I enter

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

in terminal it shows that **keytool can be found in following packages**

[image]

the file **keytool** already exists in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin` even though terminal displays this kinda message.

What's wrong with it?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin` isn't on your `$PATH`.

Just use the full path to invoke it.

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: (or add it to your PATH)

Comment: Or create a link with `ln` in your path to this location. This is what the alternative utilities do for you.